# Django crispy-forms - Custom button

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-crispy-forms

I have two buttons in my django-crispy-form

```
    self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
    self.helper.add_input(Button('cancel', 'Cancel'))
```

The submit button works just fine, the cancel button does nothing. As i am quite new to django/pyhton, how would i add a goto url (e.g. url below) to the action of the cancel button?

```
url(r'^customeroverview/$', 'customer.views.customeroverview', name='customeroverview'),
```

I have read that this is possible with JQuery, but this is something i never used. Eager to learn so if this would be the best option i am open to suggestions. Keep in mind i use the crispy form and want to use ass little html as possible.

If jQuery is used;

1. How would the jQuery code look like to open a url?
2. Do i create a new jQuery file containing the jQuery Code?
3. Do i store jQuery files in my static folder?
4. How do i call the jQuery from the button in the crispy form?

Comment: I've seen you asking questions recently and it doesn't look like you know much about what you're using. You should really learn the technologies before attempting to use them in a project. For example: jQuery is just a javascript library, it is just javascript files and it would go with the rest of your static files.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. At least it points me a bit in the direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, I used the following;

```
self.helper.add_input(Button('cancel', "Cancel", css_class='btn', onclick="javascript:location.href = '/customeroverview';"))
```

Comment: This seems a little strange, wouldn't you want to have something like reverse_lazy('customer_overview') in the js section?

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://ana-balica.github.io/2014/11/04/the-tale-of-dry-with-django-crispy-forms/) has another way:

```
HTML("""<a role="button" class="btn btn-default"
    href="{% url "some_cancel_url" %}">Cancel</a>"""),
```

So `some_cancel_url` is the [name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/) of the url you want to go to.

Seems a little hackish, but I think an anchor is better than javascript. Better for search engines, people without JS or simply for checking out the link by hovering.