# Django Crispy Forms Cancel Button That Sends User Back A Page

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django Crispy Form that I want to add a cancel button to. Unlike the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298332/django-crispy-forms-custom-button) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680908/how-to-redirect-to-url-by-cancel-button-in-django-crispy-forms), however, the user can get to the form via multiple pages, so I need to send them back to the page they came from if they cancel, not send them to a static page. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Simple javascript embed in an anchor tag of `<a href="javascript:history.back()">` got it done. Here's the full context:

```
class SetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = #blah blah
        fields = #blah blah 

    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_method = 'POST'

    helper.layout = Layout(
        # other inputs blah blah

        Row(
            Column(HTML('<a class="btn btn-warning form-group" href="javascript:history.back()">Cancel</a>')),
            Column(Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn btn-primary form-group')),
        )
    )
```

Hope this helps save someone else the time.